# Performance when using Pandas in Django

Tags: django, pandas, performance

I am working on a web application that desperately needs to depend on pandas. I was not able to find details on how Django scales when it imports big libraries. So I would like to ask:

Can I safely use full Pandas library in Django? Will it backfire in case of scaling? Is there any point in only importing what is really necessary, i.e.:
`from pandas import DataFrame` vs `import pandas as pd`?

Will Django load pandas in memory for each request that arrives at the server?